# Spring: define and wire a bean in the same class

Tags: spring

By using Java Config, how can I wire a bean in the same class when it is defined?

For example:

```
@Bean
public Foo foo() {
    return new Foo();
}

@Autowired
private Foo foo;

@Bean
public Bar bar() {
    return new Bar(foo);
}
```

Note: this code returns an error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
@Bean
public Foo foo() {
    return new Foo();
}


@Bean
public Bar bar() {
    return new Bar(foo());
}
```

Alternatively the `Bar` bean could also be configured as so:

```
@Bean
public Bar bar(Foo foo) {
    return new Bar(foo);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean, that 2 instances of `Foo` will be created?

Comment: @HerrDerb No, Spring proxies the request to make sure that only a single `Foo` bean is created